# SNMP MIB for geographical location

Tags: snmp, mib

I am writing an SNMP agent and would like to incorporate the node's identifier and/or geographical location into the data. I was wondering if there are standard MIB's for these or even a commonly used one, for instance one used by some large companies in their hardware/software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIB-II ([RFC 1213](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1213.txt)) already includes the `sysLocation` and `sysName` entries.